# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op---While switching back and forth in React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I want to switch back and forth between two React components as shown below.

Every time the **Photo** Component is invoked and the user has taken a picture. I want the Game component to mount again (thus passing **condition counter** state variable as props, to be changed) before the photo component unmounts.

React is yelling at me for **Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.**
I understand the problem that my Photo component unmounts first before the state has updated.

I have looked into several similar questions and try to adopt their solutions e.g. having an additional variable to check if the component is mounted or not and few others.

Seems like none helped me.

**Game.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import MapView, { Marker, Circle, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';
import Header from '../Components/Header';
import Footer from '../Components/Footer';
import PhotoHandler from './Photo';
import * as geolib from 'geolib';
import { event } from 'react-native-reanimated';
export default function GameArea() {
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
    const [generateTargets, setGenerateTargets] = useState(true);
    const [targets, setTargets] = useState([]);
    const [distances, setDistances] = useState([]);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);
    const [gesture, setGesture] = useState({});
    const [draggingMap, setdraggingMap] = useState(false);
    const [numofTargets, setNumofTargets] = useState(null);
    const [conditionCounter, setConditionCounter] = useState(false);
    const [photoTaken, setPhotoTaken] = useState(false);
    const [pickedLocation, setPickedLocation] = useState({
        latitude: 123,
        longitude: 123
    });
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
    const [region, setRegion] = useState({
        latitude: 123,
        longitude: 123,
        latitudeDelta: 0.001,
        longitudeDelta: 0.001
    });
    const [mapBounds, setMapBounds] = useState({
        n: null,
        s: null,
        e: null,
        w: null
    });
    const [mapRef, updateMapRef] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const verifyPermissions = async () => {
            const result = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
            if (result.status !== 'granted') {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Insufficient permissions!',
                    'You need to grant location permissions to use this app.',
                    [{ text: 'Okay' }]
                );
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
        (async () => {
            const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();
            if (!hasPermission) {
                return; 
            }
            try {
                setIsFetching(true);
                const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
                });
                setPickedLocation({
                    latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: location.coords.longitude
                });
                setRegion({
                    latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.003
                });
            } catch (err) {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Could not fetch location!',
                    'Please try again.',
                    [{ text: 'Okay' }]
                );
            }
            setIsFetching(false);
        })();
    }, []);
    const getBoundaries = () => {
        if (mapRef === null) {
            return;
        }
        mapRef
            .getMapBoundaries()
            .then((res) => {
                setMapBounds({
                    n: res.northEast.latitude,
                    e: res.northEast.longitude,
                    s: res.southWest.latitude,
                    w: res.southWest.longitude
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    const onRegionChangeComplete = (region) => {
        if (draggingMap === true && targets.length == 0) {
            getBoundaries();
            setRegion({
                latitude: region.latitude,
                longitude: region.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
                longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta
            })
            setdraggingMap(false);
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
    function handleChange(newValue) {
        setConditionCounter(newValue);
      }
    const ondraggingMap = () => {
        setdraggingMap(true);
    }
    async function generatedTargets() {
        var url = `https://xxx.yy.zz`;
        if (numofTargets == null) {
            Alert.alert(
                "Missing",
                "Enter Number of targets first",
                [
                    { text: "OK" }
                ]
            );
        }
        else {
            try {
                let response = await fetch(
                    url,
                );
                let responseJson = await response.json();
                console.log("Targets generated");
                console.log(responseJson);
                setTargets(responseJson);
                setGenerateTargets(false);
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Failed: Network Error",
                    "Try again",
                    [
                        { text: "OK" }
                    ]
                );
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('inside useEffect hook for measuring targets distances');
        var lat1 = pickedLocation.latitude; 
        var lng1 = pickedLocation.longitude;
        console.log("targets distance");
        const R = 6371;
        let targets_distance = [];
        for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180;
            const φ2 = targets[i].lat * Math.PI / 180;
            const Δφ = (targets[i].lat - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
            const Δλ = (targets[i].lng - lng1) * Math.PI / 180;
            const a = Math.sin(Δφ / 2) * Math.sin(Δφ / 2) +
                Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
                Math.sin(Δλ / 2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2);
            const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            const distance = R * c * 1000; 
            console.log('distance is'+ distance);
            if(distance <=20){
                setConditionCounter(true); //switch to photo component
                targets.splice(i, 1);
                console.log("targets after removal");
                console.log(targets);
            }
            else{
                targets_distance.push(distance);
            }
        }
        console.log(targets_distance);
        var index = 0;
        var value = targets_distance[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < targets_distance.length; i++) {
            if (targets_distance[i] < value) {
                value = targets_distance[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        console.log("smallest element is " + value + " at index " + index);
        setIndex(index);
        setDistances(targets_distance);
    }, [pickedLocation]);
   
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Inside UseEffect watch position"); 
        (async () => {
            try {
                await Location.watchPositionAsync(
                    {
                        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
                        distanceInterval: 10,
                        timeInterval: 3000,
                    },
                    (loc) => {
                        setPickedLocation({
                            latitude: loc.coords.latitude,
                            longitude: loc.coords.longitude
                        });
                    }
                );
            } catch (e) {
                Alert.alert("Error");
            }
        })();
    }, []);
    const setNumberOfTargets = (numofTargets) =>{
        setNumofTargets(numofTargets);
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header title="Crowdsourcing" />
            {conditionCounter?
            <PhotoHandler conditionCounter={setConditionCounter} onChange={handleChange}/>:
            <MapView style={styles.mapContainer}
                region={{
                    latitude: region.latitude,
                    longitude: region.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
                    longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta
                }}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                followUserLocation={true}
                ref={(ref) => updateMapRef(ref)}
                onPanDrag={ondraggingMap}
                onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}
            >
                {
                    targets.map((target, index) => (
                        <MapView.Marker
                            key={index}
                            coordinate={{
                                latitude: target.lat,
                                longitude: target.lng
                            }}
                            title={target.name}
                        />
                    ))}
            </MapView>}
            <Footer 
                Targets = {generateTargets}
                numberOfTargets = {numofTargets}
                setNumTargets = {setNumberOfTargets}
                osmTargets = {generatedTargets}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
    mapContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        marginBottom: 20
    },
    footer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#FF7F50',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
    }
});
```

**Photo.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
export default function PhotoHandler(props) {
    const [pickedLocation, setPickedLocation] = useState({
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null
    });
    const [pickedImage, setPickedImage] = useState(null); 
    const verifyPermissions = async () =>{
        const result = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        if(result.status != 'granted'){
            Alert.alert(
                'Insufficient Permissions!',
                'You need to grant camera permissions to use this app',
                [{text: 'Okay'}]
            );
            return false;
        }
            return true;

    };
    const imagetakenHandler = async () =>{
        const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();
        if(!hasPermission){
            return;
        }
        const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
              mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
              quality: 1,
              aspect: [1, 1],
              base64: true,
              exif: true
          });
        setPickedImage(image.base64);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        };
        if(pickedImage != null){
            props.onChange(false); // to switch back to Game component
            let response = fetch(`https://xxx.yy.zz`, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(console.log('SUCCESS: '+response))
                .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                });
        }
}, [pickedImage])
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {
        Alert.alert(
        "Success",
        "Take photo",
        [
          {text: "Open Camera",
          onPress: imagetakenHandler
          }
        ]
      )  
    }
    </View>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 30

    }
});
```

Comment: You'll need a wrapper component that controls that state. Your `imagetakenHandler` should include the execution of that state change. Basically something with `const [viewGame, setViewGame] = useState(true)`

Comment: How is photo component rendered from the Game component?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have updated the codebase.